# Duplicate and change a function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this code here:

```
function slideDown(){
    //get the element to slide
    var sliding = document.getElementById('slideDiv'+x);

    //add 1px to the height each time
    sliding.style.height = parseInt(sliding.style.height)+5+'px';
    t=setTimeout(slideDown,15);
    if (sliding.style.height == "401px"){clearTimeout(t);}
}
```

which gets element `slideDivx` and increases its height until it reaches `401px`.

I have 20 of these `div`s (each called `slideDiv1`, `slideDiv2`, ...) and what I want is for div 10 to start, then when it has reached about `100px` in height, I want 9 and 11 to start and so on so forth.

I've tried `setInterval` and increased `x` each time, but that doesn't work because it stops the previous `div` animating and moves on to the next one before it's finished. I think that's because I'm changing that function right?

What I'm wondering is, do I have to duplicate the function for each set of `div`s or can I automate that?

I have to be able to do it all in native JavaScript rather than jQuery because it's for a university project.

Comment: If you use paragraphs, it is easier to comprehend your question :)

Comment: uni stuff => university stuff?? in which case shouldnt you do it yourself and we could point to mistakes in your code.. create a jsfiddle with what you have right now

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply need to create slideDown with a parameter and then send your set of elements in an array like so:

```
 var elementIntervals = [];
 function animateElements(elementArray)
 {
     for(var j = 0; j < elementArray; j++)
     {
         (function(element, index)
         {
             elementIntervals[index] = setTimeout(function()
             {
                 slideDown(element, index);
             }, 15 + (100 * index));
         })(elementArray[j], j);
     }
 }

 function slideDown(sliding, index)
 {
     sliding.style.height = parseInt(sliding.style.height)+5+'px';

     if(sliding.style.height == "401px")
        clearTimeout(elementIntervals[index]);
     else
        elementIntervals[index] = setTimeout(function()
        {
            slideDown(sliding, index);
        }, 15);
 }
```

Comment: oh wow, haha i may have bitten off a bit more than i can chew here, i'm still a noob at all this. thanks heaps though, i'll have a go at sorting this out and see how i get on!

Comment: `sliding.style.height == "401px"`  suggest changing to `parseInt(sliding.style.height, 10) >= 401` in case the delta height is modified to something that won't produce exactly 401